# Instrumented unit tests have different results when running from Android Studio VS with gradlew

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-instrumentation

I came across a weird thing with my current project. If I run all the instrumented unit tests from Android Studio, none of them fail. However, if I run them using `gradlew`, there are numerous failing tests. The reasons range from JUnit assertions to Mockito verification errors (eg. "expected 4 times, but was 3").

The way I run the tests in Android Studio is by right-clicking the androidTest folder and selecting "Run tests in x.y.z".

The way I run the tests from command line is:

```
./gradlew clean app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
```

Why are these two results different? What could cause it? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, that testing results of gradlew and android studio were different. I my case it was caused by **race condition** in class, that works with data I've tested.

Fixed this problem by checking critical sections in my code and adding **reentrant locks**. Hopefully my answer can help you.